# How to gracefully handle errors in init file

Tags: init-file, error-handling

I would like a way to catch errors when running my init file, and then handle them gracefully. A lot of my most important customizations and keybindings show up at the end of my init file to make sure that other settings don't get applied over the top of them.  The problem is that when initialization aborts early, I feel totally crippled trying to debug the problem without my familiar key bindings and settings being applied.

**Is there any way to gracefully finish out the initialization process when an error occurs?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two options, neither of which are perfect, come to mind.  First, you could wrap most of your early initialization code (ie, before it gets to your customizations) in `(ignore-errors ...)`. If there *are* errors, however, there won't be a lot of feedback -- `ignore-errors` will simply return `nil`.

A more intricate option would be to wrap the potentially buggy code in a combination of `unwind-protect` and `with-demoted-errors` (with `debug-on-error` set to nil).  The latter will error out gracefully-ish at the first error it encounters and report the error message to the `*Messages*` buffer for your inspection.  Meanwhile, the rest of the `unwind-protect` body (presumably your customizations) will be evaluated.  So, e.g.:

```
(unwind-protect
    (let ((debug-on-error nil))
      (with-demoted-errors
        (message "The world is about to end")
        (sleep-for 2)
        (/ 10 0)                        ; divide by zero signals an error
        (message "This will never evaluate")
        (sleep-for 2)
        (setq some-var 5)))
  (message "Here are the unwind forms that will always evaluate")
  (sleep-for 2)
  (setq some-var 10)
  (setq another-var "puppies")
  (message "All done!"))
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't about `with-demoted-errors`. You could add a string argument to it like `"LOOK OVER HERE!!! %s"`, so you’re less likely to miss the error in the messages buffer.

Comment: @Malabarba This form of `with-demoted-errors` is only available in 24.4

Comment: @lunaryorn Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: Actually, the version I'm on is 24.3.1.

Answer (score 9):

@Dan described well how you can turn errors into messages. You can
also do whatever you want with errors by using
[`condition-case`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/condition-case).
Yet another option is to use
[`unwind-protect`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/unwind-protect).

I’ll stick to `condition-case` here, for no reason whatsoever.

#### Catching the Error

This should always guarantee your key definitions get evaluated,
regardless of what happened inside `condition-case`. Any error gets
stored inside `init-error`.

```
(defvar init-error nil 
  "The error which happened.")

(condition-case the-error
    (progn
      ;; Do the dangerous stuff here.
      (require 'what-I-want))
  (error
   ;; This is only evaluated if there's an error.
   (setq init-error the-error)))

;;; Do the safe stuff here.
(define-key uncrippling-map "\C-h" 'help!)
```

#### Throwing it Back

Afterwards, just throw the error again. There are several ways you can
do that, here’s one.

```
;;; Throw the error again here.
(when init-error
  (funcall #'signal (car init-error) (cdr init-error)))
```

Comment: `unwind-protect` causes the error to be immediately re-raised, after executing whatever code you put in its rescue clause. It's like `finally` in a language such as Java, rather than `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have pretty well covered the low-level error-handling facilities that will be useful in a case like this.  Another approach that can help is modularity.  For instance, I divide my initialization file into several different files (using `provide` as appropriate), and I load them using this function instead of `require`:

```el
(defun my/require-softly (feature &optional filename)
  "As `require', but instead of an error just print a message.

If there is an error, its message will be included in the message
printed.

Like `require', the return value will be FEATURE if the load was
successful (or unnecessary) and nil if not."
  (condition-case err
      (require feature filename) 
    (error (message "Error loading %s: \"%s\""
                    (if filename (format "%s (%s)" feature filename) feature)
                    (error-message-string err))
           nil)))
```

An error while loading a file in this way will still print a message, but it won't prevent execution of anything outside of the file where the error actually occurred.

Of course, this function isn't really that different from wrapping a `require` call in `with-demoted-errors` (I wrote it before I knew about `with-demoted-errors`), but the important point is that it you can essentially implement something like Dan's combination of `with-demoted-errors` and `unwind-protect` without wrapping (potentially very lengthy) blocks of code.

Comment: This function was exactly what I was after. My emacs boots now despite reporting an error. After that, I just load my init file and `eval-buffer`. Thanks for posting it.