# How to keep initializing regardless of errors signaled when loading init.el?

Tags: init-file, error-handling

As most emacs user, I change my init.el fairly often.
Sometimes a bug is introduced and the next time I start emacs I get an error message and a very ugly emacs without any of my keybindings. Then, I have to use this very basic emacs or (god forbid) another editor to correct the bug in init.el.

My question is: can I change it so that even if there is an error on one of the lines in init.el the rest of the script still is evaluated, and I just get an error message saying that some part failed?

Comment: found a similar Q&A [How to gracefully handle errors in init file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-to-gracefully-handle-errors-in-init-file)  but I haven't tried whether it works in the current version.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw  this kind of error-handling already but I wanted something that works with the whole script and not just some small part because I don't know which part of the init script will spawn a bug.  Essentially I was searching for something close to bash default behavior: even when there are lines that cause error, the other lines are still evaluated and you don't need to wrap this in error-catching delimitors.

Comment: Split a long piece of code into several short pieces, and use `ignore-errors` forms to wrap them.